# Getting error while converting .NET date to JavaScript date

Tags: javascript, .net

I have a function in JavaScript that receives a .NET date, but the format i am getting is not the proper. Can someone help me to figure out the issue.

Following is the JavaScript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getLoginAndDateInfo() {
    var returnedObject = {};
    returnedObject["oldOrderDate"] = <% =FormatDate( "MM/dd/yyyy",obj_rs1("CUS_ORDER_DATE"))%>;
    returnedObject["oldTurnUpDate"] = <% =FormatDate( "MM/dd/yyyy",obj_rs1("CUS_INSTALL_DATE"))%>;
    return returnedObject;
}

</script>
```

The value I am getting from `<% =FormatDate( "MM/dd/yyyy",obj_rs1("CUS_ORDER_DATE"))%> = 11/22/2016` and 
`<% =FormatDate( "MM/dd/yyyy",obj_rs1("CUS_INSTALL_DATE"))%> = 11/23/2016`.(seems to be proper)`

but the same value getting converted to JavaScript object
returnedObject["oldOrderDate"] = 0.000248015873015873 and
returnedObject["oldTurnUpDate"] = 0.00023723257418909593

Can some one help me with getting the date back to normal?
I tried searching a lot but couldn't really find the solution.

Comment: Those values are `11` divided by `22` (or `23`) divided by `2016`. You need to enclose the value in quote marks if you want a string.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan It worked. appropriate your Help.

Comment: @Claudio Redi Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are dividing every values by each other. provide the values in quote.